# grep string and sum values of upper substring

Tags: grep, sum, find, substring

I have a file.fasta like this:

```
>NODE_1_length_4203_cov_583903
CCCCCAGTAATTGTGCTGCGCGGCGATGCTAACAAGTTAAAATGCTATCGCTGAGCTAAG
AAAAAGCATGGAAGCTTGGTAAAGTACTACAGTACTACGTGAATGTACCATCAGATTGTG
TTTGTTAGTCGCGCTTTTTTTTTTTTGGAATTTTTTGGAATTTTTTTTGCGCTAACAACC
TCCTGCCGTTTTGCCCGTGCATATCGGTCACGAACAAATCTGATTACTAAACACAGTAGC
CACGGGTGGTAAGAGCAGC
.
.
.
>NODE_2_length_1959_cov_102497
ATATAAAAAAAAAAGGAACTCCAAAATGCAAAAAATGTACAAATCTAGAACTCAAAATCA
TGAATTAACAAAAAAAAAAGCCCAAAAGAAAAGCATCACTTGGAATGCAAGAATTTCATC
ATGGAACATAAAAATATAATGAAAATATAACAATCATGGAAGGCAACTGTCATCAAATAA
CAAATCTGAAAAAAATCTCAATGCATCAAGAAAAAACAGAAGCGGTAAAAGCCGTTGACC
TTCTTTGCCTAATGAAATAGAAACAATGCAGAAGTACATCCTGTACCTACTGACACTTAG
ATGTTGATGCTCCTGTTGTTACACGGGTGGTAAGAGCAGCTCTGGACTCGGCGCGCCGTT
TTGGAGGTTGGGTGGATCCTAGTCCACCTGGAAAAATGGCCACACAAAGGGTGTCTAGAA
.
.
.
```

I want to find all the occurrences for a specific string (like "CACGGGTGGTAAGAGCAGC" for example) 
I do this by using grep like:

```
grep -E "CACGGGTGGTAAGAGCAGC" file.fasta
```

then I want to sum all the "cov" values for the occurrences. so the script has to find the occurrences  and for each of them has to go up to the closer line that start with ">" (or that contain the word "cov"...is the same) and maybe print it to have a list like:

```
>NODE_1_length_4203_cov_583903
>NODE_2_length_1959_cov_102497
```

and then sum the values of the cov like: 
583903+102497= 686400‬

If you wish, it can even do it all in one solution like:
find occurrences, then sum all the values of the cov parameter (present in the upper line respect to each of the occurences that start with the symbol ">") for all the occurrances finded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` would be good choice here (below code tested on `GNU awk`)

```
$ awk '/^>/{n=split($0,a,"_")} /CACGGGTGGTAAGAGCAGC/{sum+=a[n]} END{print sum}' file.fasta
686400
```

- `/^>/{n=split($0,a,"_")}` if input line starts with `>`, create an array `a` with values based on splitting input line on `_` character. Number of elements is saved in `n` variable. Array `a` will get updated for every line starting with `>`
- `/CACGGGTGGTAAGAGCAGC/{sum+=a[n]}` if input line matches required search, only then add last element of `a` array to `sum` variable (default initial value is `0` in numeric context)
- `END{print sum}` print the results after end of input file

Also, see https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions for bioinfo specific Q&A site